# What is the right definition of the n dimensional Hodge dual and cross product?

Tags: exterior-algebra, cross-product, hodge-theory, geometric-algebras

Could you help me with those geometric algebra confusions:

Which one is the right definiton of pseudovector ?
$$(n-1)vector\\ \text{or}\\ *((n-1)vector)$$

I found one can express the hodge dual this way:
$$*((k)vector)=pseudo (n-k)vector\\*(pseudo (k)vector)=(n-k)vectors$$
But from the definition "$*:\wedge^kV\rightarrow\wedge^{n-k}V$", I don't see where pseudos come from. I think it's from $sgn(\sigma)$ or something like that

Can the link between cross product and wedge product be generalized to other dimensions using:
$$\times:\wedge^rV\times\wedge^{s-r}\rightarrow \wedge^{n-s}V$$
$vector\times vector$ would then give a pseudoscalar in 2D and a pseudobivector in 4D

Comment: Where did you find "one can express the hodge dual this way:"? Or is that your own conclusion (and if so how did you arrive at it)? What source(s) are you using? I think your question is answerable, but I need a little more context to understand what you have and what you're missing.

Comment: @MarkS. "_Generally in an n-dimensional space the Hodge dual of an order r tensor will be an anti-symmetric pseudotensor of order (n − r) and vice versa_" from [Wikipedia Pseudoscalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar) and "_pseudovectors live on different vector spaces_" [PSE pseudovectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/136127/260282) If they live in a different vector space W, hodge dual has to map V→W and W→V (my conclusion).

Comment: @MarkS. Knowing the cross product of two vectors gives a pseudovector in 3D, and their wedge product is a bivector. From a×b=*(a∧v), pseudovector=*(bivector) if *(kvector) gave (n-k)vector that would mean pseudovector=(3-2)vector=vector which is false. I conclude that the hodge dual has to map from a exterior power Λ^k(V) to a pseudo exterior power pΛ^n-k(V)

Comment: it sounds like all your confusion is coming from a particular interpretation of a single ambiguous phrase on wikipedia. Pseudoscalar and $n$vector mean the same thing. Pseudovector and $n-1$vector mean the same thing. Psuedo is just typically used to mean the corresponding multivector space of the same dimension that you would get with a higher exterior power. It's not a different kind of thing than the regular exterior powers.

Comment: But what about the demonstration I gave ? If a pseudovector and a (n-1)vector are the same, it means either the cross product of two vectors doesn't give a pseudovector or the hodge dual doesn't give a (n-k)vector

Comment: The wedge product of two (1-)vectors is a bivector. And when you think of the space of bivectors over $\mathbb R^3$, it's 3-dimensional, and you could comfortably use a lot of regular (1-)vector notation, and if you did you would give them the name "pseudovectors". The hodge dual of a k-vector is an (n-k)vector. So the hodge dual of a 1-vector is a pseudovector, no matter what n is. I'm not seeing your concern.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. But what about the cross product ?  if a×b=*(a∧v) then it mean vector×vector gives *(bivector)=n-2 vector which is not a pseudovector ?

Comment: A physicist might disagree, but I think of pseudovectors as something like "outputs of expressions where if you invert all the input vectors you don't invert the output". I would say "$a\wedge b$ treated like a vector" is definitely a pseudovector, and that "$*(a\wedge v)$" is maybe something like "a vector with the same components as the pseudovector, if you interpret the components of $a\wedge v$ appropriately".